# Google Analytics - Report Browser stats by landing page

Tags: google-analytics

I need to segment my GA stats so I can report the Browser/OS stats by landing page. Each landing page basically represents a client account so this info would be helpful in developing the client's user profile.

I can view the Browser/OS report but don't see a way to filter based on landing page (or event label)

I have been implementing event labels/values which can give me essentially an identifier for the client but then there is no way to add another dimension to that report for Technology->Browser/OS

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest is to create a custom report, that can be accessed under the Customization tab. You could build a Flat Table type report, and include Landing Page, with other desired OS and browser specific dimensions. As a metric, you can also select sessions, pageviews, or anything else, that helps to answer your questions best. You can even compare stats of various landing pages, or apply filters based on landing page.

[This is a link](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=b3oW_aTkRCOqfIgvvgt8xQ) to a sample Analytics custom report, that can be imported into your own view. (No data, just custom report configuration. [This](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1326774) is a support article about asset sharing.)